# Spark - need to improve code to fix OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, out-of-memory

I'm getting the below OutOfMemoryError error when running a Spark job. First I used the following configuration: 
`--executor-memory 4g --driver-memory 2g --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 2`

But after the error occurred I've increased driver an executor memory as well as the number of executors: `--executor-memory 8g --driver-memory 8g --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 1`

However it did not help and the error occurred again. Now I wonder if this could be caused by the way I wrote the code? I'm processing about 15k records from API. I suspect there could be a problem with how I map `salesFromApi` and apply `.toArray` in the end. Is there anything else I may improve such as repartitioning an RDD?

```
val processedSales: Array[String] = salesFromApi
.map(store => processor.doSalesProcessing(store.id).toArray

val salesRDD: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(processedSales)
val salesDf: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(salesRDD)
val specialDataDF: DataFrame = salesDf.select(...various fields from salesDf)

val salesColumns: Array[Column] = specialDataDF.columns.map(col)
salesDF.select(concat_ws(",", salesColumns : _*)).write.text(s3Dir)

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task$.serializeWithDependencies(Task.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.resourceOffer(TaskSetManager.scala:460)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your input (JSON documents), and a sample? What is the mean size of a document? Do they have some columns with huge values? Other questions : do you run Spark locally? Is there a reason that you use `toArray` on `processedSales` instead of using RDDs from the start to the end of your program?

Comment: @norbjd the input is JSON documents with data on stores and transactions. They get processed so that each store gets merged with its corresponding transactions into strings. Actually I should have written `.map(store =>...` above. Will fix it now. There are no columns with huge values. Spark job is run on a cluster. I have just removed `.toArray` (seems not to make sense) and now `processedSales` is a `Seq[String]`. Restarted the job, so will see how it goes now.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try calling .view instead of .toArray ? The view method will create a SeqView, a lazy version of the collection. With .toArray your whole 15k or so will be evaluated in that call.

Comment: What I did is got rid of Array and now return RDD after processing `val processedSales: RDD[String] = sc.makeRDD(salesFromApi
.map(store => processor.doSalesProcessing(store.id))` And then `val salesDf: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(processedSales)` Withoud additional `sc.parallelize` stuff

Answer (score 1):

This might not help, but here are a few tactics you can try to isolate where the problem is coming from. Good luck.

(1) Increase your spark overhead values to allocate more space in each container for java to run off of. This will help figure where the problem is located, this will isolate the problem to the yarn container.

```
--conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4000m"
--conf "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2000m"
```

(2) Increase your driver and executor memory to 12,20 respectively. This checks if it is related to your write.

(3) persist the input dataframe. Checks if the parsing of the JSON is causing background overhead, if we persist it we cut it out. Also try caching the rdd, we want remove as many overhead processes as possible.
    salesDF.persist
    salesDF.count

(4) If the toArray is causing the problem try changing it to a collect, it will also change the post map object into an array of strings.